# Convert JS script in twig template to simple js file

Tags: javascript, twig

I have this code that i use to show on and off multiples overlay who works pretty well :

```
{% for advert in listWorker %}
    <script>
        var clicked = true;
        /* Open when someone clicks on the span element */
        function openNav{{ advert.nom }}() {
            if(clicked){
                document.getElementById("{{ advert.nom }}").style.width = "100%";
                    clicked = false;
            }else{
                document.getElementById("{{ advert.nom }}").style.width = "0%";
                    clicked = true;
            }
        }
        /* Close when someone clicks on the "x" symbol inside the overlay */
        function closeNav{{ advert.nom }}() {
            document.getElementById("{{ advert.nom }}").style.width = "0%";
                clicked = true;
        }
    </script>
{% endfor %}
```

but it looks horrible in my twig template, is it possible to convert it in my app.js ?

Comment: That doesn't work, does it? Sure if there's more than one entry in `listWorker` you end up with all of them only changing the state of the last of them? Multiple `script` elements with top-level `var`s mean that you end up with **one** var.

Comment: it works with onclick="openNav{{ advert.nom }}()" in my button

Comment: All due respect, I don't think it does. Again, you have **one** `clicked` variable. (But I see that you do have a suffix on the function names, so they'll work.) I'm sorry I don't know anything about twig templates, but you're right to think this should be refactored. I hope someone helps!

Comment: That's what my coworker said :( , thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to overcomplicate things with creating functions that all do the same thing. Pass the id's accordingly towards the function. This you can do with `twig` but leave the javascript dynamic

```js
function openNav(id) {
  var el = document.getElementById(id);
  var clicked = el.getAttribute('data-clicked'); 

  if(clicked == 1){
    el.style.width = "100%";
    el.setAttribute('data-clicked', 0);
  }else{
    el.style.width = "0%";
    el.setAttribute('data-clicked', 1);
  }
}

function closeNav(id) {
  var el = document.getElementById(id);
  el.style.width = "0%";
  el.setAttribute('data-clicked', 1);
}
```

```css
div {
  border : 1px solid #A2A2A2;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    
  </head>
  <body>
    {% for advert in listWorker %}
    <div id="{{ advert.getId() }}">
      <ul>
        <li>Foo</li>
        <li>Foo</li>
        <li>Foo</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    
    
    {% for advert in listWorker %}
    <button type="button" onclick="openNav('{{ advert.getId() }}');">Toggle</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="closeNav('{{ advert.getId() }}');">Close</button>
    {% endfor %}
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I will try it in a few minutes

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong. Try the code snippet, works as intended

Comment: but still got ReferenceError: openNav is not defined when i press my button

Comment: now it works when i put it in my twig template directly, but not in the js file...

Comment: ok i solved it by doing : $(".btn-open").on('click',function()
    {
        openNav( $(this).attr('btn-id') );
    }); and replacing the onlick by btn-id="{{ advert.getId()}}"